# For all math symbol

Tags: math-mode, equations, symbols

How to use for all math symbol for equation like this in LaTeX
"for j = 1...J and t = 1...T"?

```
\begin{equation}\label{Con2}
\sum_{k=1}^K\sum_{\tau=1}^t q_{jk\tau} \leq BF_{jt} \cdot \sum_{\tau=1}^t w_{j\tau} \qquad
\forall j
\textrm{for}\quad j=1,\ldots,J \quad \textrm{and} \quad t=1,\ldots,T
\end{equation}
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question? What's the problem?

Comment: Are you asking about `\forall`?

Comment: Maybe you should try https://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html

Comment: try `j \in \integer` from china2e package.

Answer (score 4):

Using `\forall` and making a slight change one option is seen by:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}   
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=1}^K\sum_{\tau=1}^t q_{jk\tau} \leq BF_{jt} \cdot \sum_{\tau=1}^t w_{j\tau} \qquad
\forall \quad 1 \leq j \leq J \quad \textrm{and} \quad 1 \leq t \leq T
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the response but if i want something like \forall j and \forall k. How to write where j and k not starting from 1 but from 2 or not end at J but something else.

Comment: @macscm  Depending on what the something else is then to format would be changed. For example it could be `\forall j, k \in \mathbb{N}_0` with use of `\usepackage{amssymb}`. Many other examples exist.